# best way to show a image near my header section of tableview with header title

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, header

I have to show a image near my header section of tableview with header title.Can anybody suggest the best way of doing it?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a navigationbar with a title and an image:

```
    // show image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bar_icon.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 40, 40);
    //self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;

    // label
    UILabel *tmpTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 0, 200, 40)];
    tmpTitleLabel.text = @"Mannschaft";
    tmpTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tmpTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tmpTitleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

    // create new view
    CGRect applicationFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);
    UIView * newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
    [newView addSubview:imageView];
    [newView addSubview:tmpTitleLabel];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = newView;

    [imageView release];
    [tmpTitleLabel release];
```